# SherlockFragmentActivity issue with action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

Above is my activity code. Problem : Two action bars are shown, one is default and other is sherlock's. I need to show only sherlock one, Any Idea?

Comment: Never seen this one before. Have you tried removing this: `setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);` and setting it only in the Manifest file?

Comment: Seriously?? Notch one up for a _fluke_ then. ;-)